# Where is the navigation manager in VBulletin - 4.1.11?

Tags: vbulletin

I can't find the navigation manger in new version of vBulletin. It is under `settings` in newer versions but can't see it now in the 4.1.11 version. If there isn't any, how can I edit the navigation items?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your forum is running VB 4.1.11 - The Navigation Manager was added in 4.2.0. You should upgrade to 4.2.x to get access to it. In 4.1.11 all changes required manual edits or plugins.

[vBulletin 4.2 Release Note](https://www.vbulletin.com/forum/forum/vbulletin-announcements/vbulletin-announcements_aa/411367-vbulletin-4-2-full-has-been-released-vbulletin-com-upgraded)

The release contains:

- Activity Stream
- **Navigation Manager**
- Members who have Visited Today

**UPDATE:**

**1.** If you don't want to upgrade you vBulletin version, you should do that manually
and it depends on your style

for example some default styles navigation bar is in head file 
and you can edit from:

```
Admincp > Styles & Templates > Style Manager > Your Template > Edit Templates > header
```

If you want to know exact path of navigation bar for your style, you can search  some codes of your style navigation bar in `style manager` search form

an exaple for navigation bar code:

```
<div class="cnavbar">
    <center>
        <div id="cnavtabs" class="cnavtabs">

            <ul>
                <li><a href="Your URL">Link Text</a></li>
                <li><a href="Your URL">Link Text</a></li>
                <li><a href="Your URL">Link Text</a></li>
                <li><a href="Your URL">Link Text</a></li>
                <li><a href="Your URL">Link Text</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </center>
</div>
```

and maybe css code:

```
.cnavbar
{
    width:100%;
    height:32px; ( Change Height Here )
    background-color:#150517; ( Change Background Color Here )
    border-bottom:1px solid #666;
}
#cnavtabs
{
    width:960px; ( Change width Here )
    height:100%;
}
```

**2.** On the other hand if you don't want to do that manually you should find or request Mod or plugin that support vBulletin 4.1.x

This is a Mod to create a custom navigation for all 4.x.x version of vBulletin

[[DBTech] DragonByte Custom Navigation v1 (vB4)](https://www.vbulletin.org/forum/showthread.php?t=296169)

Hope to help you

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo I update my answer and suggest two way to do that

Comment: I already did that. I just wanted to know the exact answer. Up-voted and marked as answered for the effort.